# How to align a icon with border left in a custom card component in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a custom card component for my application. This is the design I made in sketch.

[image: design]

I am using [this source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp) to make a custom card. I am also using the [Bootstrap Framework](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) and I didn't see a card component that fits my design.

This is my custom code from I wrote:

```css
.card {
  width: 20%;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.card-icon-right {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John </b></h4>
    <p>Engineer</p>
    <div class="card-icon-right float-right">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I don't get the custom div I made (`card-icon-right`) to the same height as the `container` class. I also tried the cards of bootstrap but I don't get the preferred width.

How can I get the `car-icon-right` class the same height as the `container`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.card {
  width: 20%;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.card-icon-right {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-icon-right p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John </b></h4>
    <p>Engineer</p>
    <div class="card-icon-right"><p>X</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap’s default card class has the `flex-direction: column` You have to change this to
`flex-direction: row`

```css
.card {     
  width: 20%;
  flex-direction: row !important;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.card-icon-right
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-left: 2px solid grey;
    width: 10%;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John </b></h4> 
    <p>Engineer</p>   
     
  </div>
  <div class="card-icon-right"> X </div>
</div>
```